# attr_accessor coming in empty in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a field that does not live permanently on the model so I am using attr_accessor on the model to make it available for use, however it is always returning nil when I try to access it.

The form field:

```
<%= text_field_tag :discount_code, nil, maxlength: "12", class: "span2" %>
```

The controller:

```
def an_action
   @job = Job.find(session[:job_id])
   @job.some_method
end
```

The model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :discount_code

    def some_method
        if !self.discount_code.blank?
        do some logic
    end
end
```

The above statement never executes as it is always evaluating to nil.

The value of the field is available in the controller as a param w/out issue:

```
discount_code: test50
action: process_payment
controller: jobs
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you setting the model attribute (e.g., is it accessible)? (And beerlington is correct; it's difficult to tell how/when you're trying to use it.) And you don't need `self` to refer to attr_accessor attributes, even when setting, unlike persisted attributes.)

Comment: I hate when people put dummy code in instead of real code, because your 'controller' would never work because @job.id would be nil. Please use real code, it's confusing enough as it is.

Comment: Sorry Karpie - I assumed it would make it easier this way.  Will try to use real code in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you *could* autoset the corresponding form value to the instance of the class. But you used a text_field_tag, which sets params[:discount_tag], when what you needed was a param[:job][:discount_tag]

For that, you could use:

```
<%= f.text_field :discount_code, maxlength: 12, class: "span2" %>
```

Which is indeed a lot more elegant.

Comment: Yes, but it sits within `<%= form_tag "/jobs/process_payment", id: 'payment_form', class: "form-horizontal" do %>` which I believe means I cannot use f.text_field.

Comment: You should use `form_for` instead of `form_tag`

Comment: Yes - but this is a form just for processing a credit card and is not tied to any model.  Only the resulting transaction token is used/stored on the model....but perhaps I should try/refactor?

Comment: That doesn't matter, you can still use the form-based helpers even if an attribute is not persisted.

Answer (score 0):

If the sample code you posted is truly what is in your model, then the problem is just the context in which you are trying to access the discount_code. The discount_code value will only be available to an instance of the model, but in your case, you are trying to access it in the Class context.

You can override the setter method to confirm that it's actually being set:

```
def discount_code=(code)
  # If you get here, then the value is being set!
  super
end
```

Comment: Thanks - i've updated the question to be a bit more clear.  Referenced from an instance of that model.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I naively thought that attr_accesor would autoset the corresponding form value to the instance of the class as Rails does with actual database fields (i.e. form_for(@jobs).

I simply needed to add the below in the controller:

```
@job.discount_code = params[:discount_code]
```

Thank you for setting me on the right track.

Comment: The answer from YuriAlbuquerque is more likely what you want. It will require less code to use `form_for @model` than to use a plain `form_tag` and do everything manually.

Comment: Yes - but this is a form just for processing a credit card and is not tied to any model. Only the resulting transaction token is used/stored on the model....but perhaps I should try/refactor?